# Shutdown Ubuntu using upstart

Tags: shutdown, upstart

I have a process which is started by Upstart. It will try to respwan the process  n number of times on failure  and after that if it fails, I want to restart my Ubuntu. I tried `telinit`, `halt` etc in the `*.conf` file.

But I am getting an error

```
 stop: Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
```

Is it possible to achieve through Upstart or else is there another way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below link helped me for a solution.

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/upstart-devel/2009-December/001140.html

> This means that you could just do (as a file in /etc/init):
>
> ```
>   start on stopped $JOB RESULT=failed PROCESS=respawn
>   exec /sbin/reboot
> ```
>
> You can make that more generic if you like, a job that should cause a
>   reboot when respawn fails could have (in its config file):
>
> ```
>   env REBOOT_ON_RESPAWN_FAIL=1
>   export REBOOT_ON_RESPAWN_FAIL
> ```
>
> Then your reboot job could match it with:
>
> ```
>   start on stopped REBOOT_ON_RESPAWN_FAIL=1 \
>       RESULT=failed PROCESS=respawn
>   exec /sbin/reboot
> ```

Comment: Hi Spike, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers)